# Disable panding in achart engine android

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using the achartengine to draw chart on Adnroid application, so when i call the method "getBarChartView" to create a view and add it to a RelativeLayout.

In settings i added this

```
public GraphicalView createChartView() {

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(mColorBar);
        renderer.setOrientation(mOrientation);

        // settings the chart
        setChartSetting(renderer, mChartTitle, mXAxisTitle, mYAxisTitle,
                mXmin, mXmax, mYmin, mYmax, mAxesColor, mLabelColor,
                mGridColor, IChartInterface.ALIGN_CENTER,
                IChartInterface.ALIGN_RIGHT, mTopMargin, mLeftMargin,
                mBottomMargin, mRightMargin);

   // disable the pan
        renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);

        renderer.setShowGridX(isShowGridX);
        renderer.setShowGridY(isShowGridY);

        renderer.setZoomRate(mZoomRate);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(mBarSpacing);
    }

    return ChartFactory.getBarChartView(mContext,
                buildBarDataset(convertToString(mTitles), mValues),
                renderer, Type.STACKED);

}
```

But it doesn't work, i still can use two finger to pan it. so the chart's shape go to unexpectedness shape. Could anyone tell me why and how can i disable pan on the view?

Thanks for any helps
Clark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct `setZoomEnabled` method. For the `XYChart` charts like `BarChart`, `LineChart`,... it is:

```
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Dan.
It works like a charm. I thought setZoomEnabled(true) is enough to disable panding.